# why there is a error under the R in android studio?

Tags: android

i recently downloaded android studio. there i saw an error under R in MainActivity.kt(R.layout.activity_main). do i need to import?

here is the picture of the error and when the cursor is placed on the error:-
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3wVh.png)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teF7r.png)

although the red cross has gone from the APP button, when i run the code, only the emulator runs, but the code doesn't displays.
what should i do?

Comment: Nobody, who has not seen your other question by chance, will know what the "red cross" is about.

Comment: try to clean your code (Build > Clean) and build again

Comment: i have tried a lot, but nothing happens. when i press alt + enter, then it asks me to import, but when i click on import, then it gives a long list, like R.androidx.combat and so on. so... which one should i use
??

Answer (score 0):

goto File->invalidate caches/restart->invalidate and restart.